# nested structures and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I dork this up just about every time I jump back into a C project. I'm getting a segfault when attempting to access a structure within a structure. Let's say I have the following (simplified) structures for a game:

```
struct vector {
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct ship {
    struct vector *position;
};

struct game {
    struct ship *ship;
} game;
```

And a function to initialize the ship:

```
static void
create_ship(struct ship *ship)
{
    ship = malloc(sizeof(struct ship));
    ship->position = malloc(sizeof(struct vector));
    ship->position->x = 10.0;
}
```

Then down in main():

```
int main() {
    create_ship(game.ship);
    printf("%f\n", game.ship->position->x); // <-- SEGFAULT
}
```

Comment: as a side note you could use things like `typedef struct {float x; float y;} vector;` so you don't have to say `struct` each time you use the type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are passing `game.ship` by value, so inside `create_ship` the variable `ship` is just a copy of that pointer, and it just changes the copy. When the function returns, the pointer to what you `malloc`ed is lost and the effects of the function are not visible outside it, except for the memory leak.

You need to pass a pointer to the pointer and modify `game.ship` through that:

```
static void
create_ship(struct ship **ship)
{
    *ship = malloc(sizeof(struct ship));
    (*ship)->position = malloc(sizeof(struct vector));
    (*ship)->position->x = 10.0;
}
```

And

```
create_ship(&game.ship);
```

Or perhaps a better way would be to do as Johnny Mopp suggests in the comments, return the pointer from the function instead of modifying one outside of it:

```
static struct ship* create_ship()
{
    struct ship* s = malloc(sizeof(struct ship));
    s->position = malloc(sizeof(struct vector));
    s->position->x = 10.0;

    return s;
}
```

And

```
game.ship = create_ship();
```

And of course, what you have `malloc`ed, don't forget to `free`.

Comment: Or ship * create_ship() { ... }

Comment: true, there's more than one road to Rome.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks, I wanted the OP to know why it wasn't working, but I added a bit about what you were suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass by reference:

```
static void create_ship(struct ship **ship);
```

and

```
create_ship(&game.ship);
```

otherwise the allocated structure is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Your `create_ship` function isn't actually changing `game.ship`, since the argument is *passed-by-value*. In the `create_ship` function, only a *copy* is being changed. So after the call, `game.ship` remains uninitialized (or `NULL`, or whatever it's value is before the call). Consequently you also lose the reference to the newly allocated ship, and leak memory.

You'll need to pass a pointer to a pointer in order to change it:

```
static void create_ship(struct ship **ship)
{
    *ship = malloc(sizeof(struct ship));
    // ...
```

And in the call: `create_ship(&game.ship);`

You could also opt to pass out the new ship as the function return value:

```
static ship *create_ship()
{
    struct ship *ship = malloc(sizeof(struct ship));
    // ...

    return ship;
}

// ...

game.ship = create_ship();
```