# struct of structs as argument

Tags: c++, c, function, struct, arguments

I have quite a big structure which has inside of it other structures, then I want to pass this structure of structures as an argument of a function. Anyone knows how to do it or may give me an example please!

Comment: make up your mind, its either C or C++.

Comment: Just pass it? It should work fine.

Comment: The contents of the structure are irrelevant. You just *pass* a structure, then in your function you *access* the structure within the structure.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a example is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694902/nested-structures-and-pointers

Comment: if c++ is an option, consider using classes and inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct B {
   //your struct..
};
struct A {  
    B b;
};

void foo(struct A a)
{ 
   a.b + ???....
   //you function
}
```

Comment: @icepack Passing data by value? Especially if it is a large data structure?

Answer (score 2):

If your function doesn't need to modify any of the struct's contents, you can pass it like you would any other argument:

```
struct bigStruct {
  struct aStruct a;
  struct anotherStruct b;
  struct someOtherStruct c;
  ...
};

void foo( struct bigStruct s )
{
  do_something_with( s.a );
  do_something_else_with( s.b );
  ...
}
```

If you need to write to any of the struct's members, you will need to pass a *pointer* to the struct, and use the `->` operator to access its members:

```
void bar( struct bigStruct *p )
{
   do_something_with( p->a );
   do_something_else_with( p->b );
   ....
}
```

Sometimes it's also desirable to use a pointer if the struct type is *very* large.

Note that you only need to use the `->` operator when dealing with a pointer to a struct.  In our struct definition above, `a`, `b`, and `c` are regular struct types, so we'd access their members with `.`.  For example, assuming the following definition for `aStruct`:

```
struct aStruct {
  int ival;
  double dval;
  char name[20];
};
```

we'd access those members through `p` like so:

```
printf( "%d\n", p->a.ival );
printf( "%f\n", p->a.dval );
printf( "%s\n", p->a.name );
```

Now, if our bigStruct was defined like

```
struct bigStruct {
  struct aStruct *a;
  ...
};
```

then we'd need to use the `->` operator for both the children of `p` and the children of `p->a`:

```
printf( "%d\n", p->a->ival );
printf( "%f\n", p->a->dval );
printf( "%s\n", p->a->name );
```

Answer (score 0):

A structure may have both basic types and complex types as members. Passing a structure that has members that are in turn structures does not differ from passing a structure that only has basic type members.